# Sharing Set not working - Customer Community

Tags: community, sharing, customer-community, sharing-sets

UPDATE:
Nothing is working, Quote is getting shared from the trigger.

I have two custom profiles Employee and Employer cloned from Customer Community Plus Login Profile.

I have tried to set  Sharing Sets to give access to one of custom objects Quote__c. The sharing set is working only for Employer Profile and not for Employee profile.

I have also queried the Quote__share object.

Here are the screenshots .. what can be the issue?

[image: Sharing Set]

[image: Query Result]